# Are side panels still not supported on the MS Teams web version?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Where can I clarify whether or not side panels are currently supported in MS Teams web client?  I have built a Teams App and enabled scope group chat and context meetingSidePanel.  I also added sidePanel to meetingSurfaces.  I see it in the Teams Client but not the web client.  The [can't find any documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/design/designing-apps-in-meetings#:%7E:text=In%20a%20meeting%2C%20users%20can,select%20the%20app%20they%20want.) that says the web client is not supported. I also looked here but there is no mention of it not working on the web client: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msteams-meetings-apps/2-understand-meeting-apps

Please help clarify.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in response, We are also able to repro the issue. We have raised a bug for the same. If it is not supported, then we will get the document updated.

Comment: @vangj:  It's not supported currently